# Button Destroying Itself and Not Showing Up

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button to run my function which is supposed to count the number of each type of arrow in a Stepmania .sm file. It's not running properly or showing up

```
def openSmFile():
    folPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return folPathdef checkDirections():

def CheckDirections()
    folPath = openSmFile()
    for fpath in glob.iglob(f'{folPath}/*'):
        if (fpath.endswith('.sm')):
            file = open(fpath,"r")
            lines = []
            lines = file.readlines()

            left = 0
            down = 0
            up = 0
            right = 0
            beats = 0

            for line in lines:  
                i = 0
                if not ("," in  line or "." in line or "#" in line or ";" in line or "-" in line or line == ""):
                    for alpha in line:
                        if i == 0 and alpha != "0":
                            left += 1
                        if i == 1 and alpha != "0":
                            down += 1
                        if i == 2 and alpha != "0":
                            up += 1
                        if i == 3 and alpha != "0":
                            right += 1
                        i += 1
                        beats += 1
                
            print ("There are " + str(left) + " lefts in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(down) + " downs in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(up) + " ups in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(right) + " rights in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(beats) + " beats.")
            nameDirections = ["left", "down", "up", "right"]
            directions = [left, down, up, right] 



runThrough = Button(root, padx = 50, pady = 50, text = "Click to print number of each arrow", command = checkDirections)
```

Comment: Where do you actually add the Button to the UI using `place()` or `pack()`?

Comment: you haven't added the button to the screen using `grid`, `pack`, or `place`

Comment: As part of a [mcve], please [edit] to show where `root` is defined and how you maybe add widgets to it, or not. For example, you could `place()` the button outside of the window frame, or just not all the button at all

Comment: Also, you have a syntax error at `return folPathdef checkDirections():`

Answer (score 1):

There's not quite enough information to go on here, but as others have mentioned you aren't actually adding the button to the UI with a geometry manager like `pack()`, `place()` or `grid()`. Try...

```
runThrough = Button(
    root,
    padx=50, 
    pady=50, 
    text="Click to print number of each arrow", 
    command=checkDirections
)
runThrough.pack()  # <-- insert the button into the UI
```

Comment: No problem! If you found this helpful, please accept the answer. Otherwise (if it didn't work) let me know and maybe I can help you find another solution! :)